# Call a component method from another component with ref

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, modal-dialog, react-props, react-ref

I'm trying to call a `show` method of my `Modal` component when the user clicks the `<button>` in the `App` component, but it doesn't work.

I use a `ref` to access the `Modal` component from the `App` component.

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
  }

  show() {
    console.log('show');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>...</div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.modalRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal ref={this.modalRef}/>

        <button id="myBtn" onClick={ this.modalRef.show }>
          Call show modal method
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Tried with the regular `ref` approach and it seems be working with all your existing code

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  show = () => {
    console.log("show");
  };

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal ref={ref => (this._modal = ref)} />
        <button id="myBtn" onClick={() => this._modal.show()}>
          call show modal method
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-z893s?file=/index.js:77-461

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: No worries, happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You would usually do that passing down a prop rather than calling a method directly on the component:

```
const Modal = ({
  isVisible,
}) => {   
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`The modal has been ${ isVisible ? 'opened' : 'closed' }.`);
  }, [isVisible]);

  return (
    <div className={ cx({ ['isVisible']: isVisible }) }>...</div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    // Toggle the `isModalVisible` value:
    setIsModalVisible(prevIsModalVisible => !prevIsModalVisible);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal isVisible={ isModalVisible } />

      <button onClick={ handleButtonClick }>
        { isModalVisible ? 'Close' : 'Open'} Modal
      </button>
    </div>
  )
};
```